# How to save wallet after create_address?

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

If I create a new address (create_address from rpc), the state of the wallet is not saved while rpc daemon is running. If the daemon crashes, will I lose the generated keys? What are possible solutions?

p.s. Beryllium Bullet 0.13.0.2-release, OS Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`create_address` does not generate wallet key files, it creates a subaddress. Therefore even if the wallet RPC crashed, you would not lose anything. The wallet can still receive funds sent to that subaddress also.

Comment: I hope this is true, but for sure I will use random payment_id and coinbase address. Thx 4 answer

Comment: It is true. "Accounts are deterministically derived from the root private key along with subaddresses." : https://monerodocs.org/public-address/subaddress/

Comment: This can also create problems I think. I planed to give each client an unique subaddress. I will not lose coins, but I will not be able to detect a payment to the subaddress if the daemon crashes

Comment: Well no, you cannot do anything with the RPC if it has hypothetically crashed. You would restart it though and like normal, it would scan blocks since last scan which would pick up any received payments.